# What does “You’ll never make kids pay attention in class with the world in a state of ubiquit-ass” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I need some help from Native speakers to understand the sentence below.

> “You’ll never make kids pay attention in class with the world in a state of ubiquit-ass”. Ubiquit-ass, like kids looking at ass.

This is from a musician talking about a lyric of his song.  Does it mean something like you’ll never get any attention in class by just being stupid, or an ass?
I think “ubiquit-ass” here is a play on words (ubiquitous), and “with the world” is just for emphasis. But I can’t really get what he’s trying to say here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall meaning of this sentence is that the world is filled with sexual imagery, and since there's nothing as stimulating as that to look at in a classroom, it's impossible to get kids to focus.

The words "with the world" is not just for emphasis. It's part of the larger phrase, "with the world in a state of ubiquit-ass", where "with" is a preposition that has the roughly same meaning as "given that" or "because".

Comment: With **ass** being a reference to sexual imagery and a play (i.e. wordplay) on the word ubiquitous, which means *everywhere* -- *ubiquit-ass* means *sexual imagery/themes everywhere.*

Comment: There might be a nuance that kids of a certain age, especially boys, are prone to be distracted by attractive members of the opposite sex females, who seem to be everywhere they look (seem to be ubiquitous). This happens irrespective of 'sexual imagery'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think so, since "the state of the world" refers to a current time, a particular situation in the present, but kids of a certain age being distracted by each other predates our species.

Comment: To a teenage boy, the world is full of 'ass'. Believe me. I was one.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the interpretations and explanations. The meaning is definitely not what I thought it would be haha. I really didn’t expect it would mean something sexual.